# Do I need to obtain a visa to look for a job in Schengen area for citizens of foreign nation which are not required visa to enter the area?

Tags: schengen, eu, norway, georgian-citizens

I live in Georgia and visa is not required for Georgian citizens to visit Schengen area up to 90 days in period of 180 days.

Last year I visited 5 counties in EU including Norway, I was fascinated by Norway's cold, harsh climate and nature. (It may be unusual but I like cold weather).

As a website developer I intend to go to Norway and look for a job there but I wonder, Am I required to hold a visa to look for a job?

Comment: Nope, but an immigration officer may deny you entry as they think you may work illegally and not return home. Have a look at jobs online that will offer visa sponsorship and apply with a good portfolio.

Comment: To close-voters: this is not a question about long-term immigration. The asker wants to make short visits to **look for** a job. The long-term immigration happens later in the process.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I agree with your comment, and as far as I see it that means that this question is on topic both here and at [Expatriates.SE].  It would be remiss of us not to point out the existence of that site, for the benefit both of D. Elp. and of others who might find this question.

Comment: @BritishSam actually it seems (from o.m.'s answer) that it's possible to enter without a visa, find a job, and apply for a residence permit, so the immigration officer would only be likely to come to the suspicion that the traveler would work illegally if the traveler seems unable or unwilling for some reason to engage with the bureaucracy and wait for the application to be approved.

Comment: @phoog, it could also be a problem if the traveler does not fit the profile of a highly paid professional, or if he seems unable to pay for the planned stay.

Comment: @o.m. definitely (though it's "skilled worker," not "highly paid professional").  I was writing under the assumption that the traveler obviously qualifies as a "skilled worker" and meets the financial requirement as well.  There are other circumstances that could lead to denial of entry, of course, such as a criminal history.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [this](https://www.udi.no/en/want-to-apply/work-immigration/job-seekers/?c=geo#link-6239) Norwegian site? You can come an *seek* a job but you cannot *work* without a permit.

Comment: Did you try the "how to apply" button?  To apply inside Norway, it's necessary to have "legal stay" there, but it's not clear to me whether entering as a visa-free visitor counts.

Comment: @phoog, I assumed a visa-free entry was legal stay, since it clearly isn't illegal. Requiring a residence permit to apply for a residence permit would be weird, except in the case of recent graduates.

Comment: It clearly isn't illegal, true, but I wonder whether something might have been lost in translation (perhaps the Norwegian word for "stay" is a word that excludes "short stay").  The more I think about it, though, the more I suspect that you are correct.  For example, if it were necessary to have a specific type of visa before applying for a job-seeker's permit, they wouldn't have a section for "Skilled job seeker with a visa free citizenship."